# implicit declaration in parsing rule warning antlrworks 2

Tags: antlrworks

I always get implicit declaration in parsing rule warning, when coding all examples from antlr v4 inside antlrworks 2. for my simple rule like :

```
type
  : 'Integer'
  | 'Character'  
  | 'Real'       
  | 'String'     
  | 'Short'      
  | 'Long'       
  | 'Double'        
  | 'Signed'        
  | 'Unsigned'   
  | 'Boolean'    
  | structTag    
  | enumTag      
  | declarator   
  ;
```

Can anybody give me solution that warning, at last solution for example above.
thank

Answer (score 1):

The warning is to inform you that you will have no way in code to know if your `type` is an identifier, character, real, etc., because you have not assigned named token types to the corresponding tokens. You can resolve this warning by creating named lexer rules for each of your tokens:

```
INTEGER : 'Integer';
CHARACTER : 'Character';
```

You do not have to change the `type` rule after adding these new definitions, but after adding the definitions you will be able to check if a token type is `INTEGER` or `CHARACTER` as part of your parser result handling code.

Comment: great, its work, I am grateful bout that, but is there a way other than having to write tokens one by one in lexer rule ? Sory I am newbie using antlrworks2

Comment: why       (    LINE_COMMENT 
       |    COMMENT
       |    WS
       )*